# keras.backend is not defined for variational autoencoder model

Tags: keras, keras-layer, autoencoder

I created a Variational Autoencoder model. To do the sampling, I created the following method:

```
from keras import backend as k
def sampling(args):
    z_mean , z_log_var=args
    batch=k.shape(z_mean)[0]
    dim=k.int_shape(z_mean)[1]

    epsilon=k.random_normal(shape=(batch,dim))
    return z_mean + k.exp(0.5 * z_log_var) * epsilon
```

this is the model architecture:

```
def create_variationalModel(original_dim):
    input_shape=(original_dim,)
    intermidiate_dim=58
    batch_size=10
    latent_dim=3
    epochs=100

    inputs=Input(shape=input_shape,name="encoder_input")
    x= Dense(units=original_dim,activation="tanh")(inputs) 
    x= Dense(units=int(original_dim/2),activation="tanh")(x) 
    x1= Dense(units=int(original_dim/4),activation="tanh")(x) 
    x2= Dense(units=int(original_dim/8),activation="tanh")(x1) 
    x3= Dense(units=10,activation="tanh")(x2) 
    z_mean=Dense(latent_dim,name="z_mean")(x3)
    z_log_var=Dense(latent_dim,name="z_log_var")(x3)

    z=Lambda(sampling,output_shape=(latent_dim,),name="z")([z_mean,z_log_var])


    encoder=Model(inputs,[z_mean,z_log_var,z],name="encoder")
    encoder.summary()

    latent_inputs=Input(shape=(latent_dim,),name="z_sampling")
    x= Dense(units=10,activation="tanh")(latent_inputs) 
    x1=Dense(units=int(original_dim/8),activation="tanh")(x)
    x2=Dense(units=int(original_dim/4),activation="tanh")(x1)
    x3=Dense(units=int(original_dim/2),activation="tanh")(x2)
    x3=Dense(units=original_dim,activation="tanh")(x3)
    outputs=Dense(units=original_dim,activation="sigmoid")(x3)

    decoder=Model(latent_inputs,outputs,name="decoder")
    decoder.summary()


    outputs=decoder(encoder(inputs)[2])
    vae = Model(inputs,outputs,name="vae_mlp")


    reconstruction_loss=mse(inputs,outputs)
    reconstruction_loss*=original_dim


    kl_loss = 1 + z_log_var -k.square(z_mean) - k.exp(z_log_var)
    kl_loss=k.sum(kl_loss,axis=-1)
    kl_loss*=-0.5
    vae_loss=k.mean(reconstruction_loss+kl_loss)
    vae.add_loss(vae_loss)
    plot_model(vae,to_file='vae.png',show_shapes=True)
    vae.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(),loss="mean_squared_error",metrics=["mae"])
    return vae
```

the after training the model and test it, I decide to save it like this:

```
vae.save("./models/vae.h5")
```

but when I tried to load the model like this:

```
model = load_model("./models/vae.h5")
```

I have this issue:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         1 #load model
>   ----> 2 model = load_model("./models/vae.h5")
>         3 # summarize model.
>         4 model.summary()
>         5 with open("./models/LabelEncoders_dic.pickle","rb") as f:
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py
>   in load_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
>       490                 os.remove(tmp_filepath)
>       491             return res
>   --> 492         return load_function(*args, **kwargs)
>       493 
>       494     return load_wrapper
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py
>   in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
>       582     if H5Dict.is_supported_type(filepath):
>       583         with H5Dict(filepath, mode='r') as h5dict:
>   --> 584             model = _deserialize_model(h5dict, custom_objects, compile)
>       585     elif hasattr(filepath, 'write') and callable(filepath.write):
>       586         def load_function(h5file):
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py
>   in _deserialize_model(h5dict, custom_objects, compile)
>       272         raise ValueError('No model found in config.')
>       273     model_config = json.loads(model_config.decode('utf-8'))
>   --> 274     model = model_from_config(model_config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
>       275     model_weights_group = h5dict['model_weights']
>       276
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py
>   in model_from_config(config, custom_objects)
>       625                         '`Sequential.from_config(config)`?')
>       626     from ..layers import deserialize
>   --> 627     return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
>       628 
>       629
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/layers/**init**.py
>   in deserialize(config, custom_objects)
>       163     globs['Model'] = models.Model
>       164     globs['Sequential'] = models.Sequential
>   --> 165     return deserialize_keras_object(config,
>       166                                     module_objects=globs,
>       167                                     custom_objects=custom_objects,
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py
>   in deserialize_keras_object(identifier, module_objects,
>   custom_objects, printable_module_name)
>       142             custom_objects = custom_objects or {}
>       143             if has_arg(cls.from_config, 'custom_objects'):
>   --> 144                 return cls.from_config(
>       145                     config['config'],
>       146                     custom_objects=dict(list(_GLOBAL_CUSTOM_OBJECTS.items()) +
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py
>   in from_config(cls, config, custom_objects)    1054         # First,
>   we create all layers and enqueue nodes to be processed    1055
>   for layer_data in config['layers']:
>   -> 1056             process_layer(layer_data)    1057     1058         # Then we process nodes in order of layer depth.
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py
>   in process_layer(layer_data)    1039             from ..layers import
>   deserialize as deserialize_layer    1040 
>   -> 1041             layer = deserialize_layer(layer_data,    1042                                       custom_objects=custom_objects)    1043
>   created_layers[layer_name] = layer
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/layers/**init**.py
>   in deserialize(config, custom_objects)
>       163     globs['Model'] = models.Model
>       164     globs['Sequential'] = models.Sequential
>   --> 165     return deserialize_keras_object(config,
>       166                                     module_objects=globs,
>       167                                     custom_objects=custom_objects,
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py
>   in deserialize_keras_object(identifier, module_objects,
>   custom_objects, printable_module_name)
>       142             custom_objects = custom_objects or {}
>       143             if has_arg(cls.from_config, 'custom_objects'):
>   --> 144                 return cls.from_config(
>       145                     config['config'],
>       146                     custom_objects=dict(list(_GLOBAL_CUSTOM_OBJECTS.items()) +
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py
>   in from_config(cls, config, custom_objects)    1073
>   node_data = node_data_list[node_index]    1074
>   try:
>   -> 1075                             process_node(layer, node_data)    1076     1077                         # If the node does not have all
>   inbound layers
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py
>   in process_node(layer, node_data)    1023             # and building
>   the layer if needed.    1024             if input_tensors:
>   -> 1025                 layer(unpack_singleton(input_tensors), **kwargs)    1026     1027         def process_layer(layer_data):
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py
>   in symbolic_fn_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
>        73         if _SYMBOLIC_SCOPE.value:
>        74             with get_graph().as_default():
>   ---> 75                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
>        76         else:
>        77             return func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py
>   in **call**(self, inputs, **kwargs)
>       487             # Actually call the layer,
>       488             # collecting output(s), mask(s), and shape(s).
>   --> 489             output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
>       490             output_mask = self.compute_mask(inputs, previous_mask)
>       491
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/layers/core.py
>   in call(self, inputs, mask)
>       714         else:
>       715             self._input_dtypes = K.dtype(inputs)
>   --> 716         return self.function(inputs, **arguments)
>       717 
>       718     def compute_mask(self, inputs, mask=None):
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/layers/core.py
>   in sampling(args)
>
> **NameError: name 'k' is not defined**

**K** comes from **from keras import backend as k**. even y adding this importation, I have the same error. Can anyone know how to fix this ?